# deselect the previously selected cell in tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have Table View with Multiple sections in it.
I want to allow only one row selected...My tableview's Selection Property is Set to:SingleSelectioin

Now I am doing this to set the checkmark for selected row

```
if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)

{
       [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

else
{
     [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Now what I want is that when I select any other cell, the previously selected cell should be set back to unselected.

I have tried with this

```
lastIndexpath=indexPath;
```

and then

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexpath animated:YES];
```

but it gives me bad access on lasIndexPath

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address= 0xfe000008)
```

Kindly Help me with this

any New Suggestions are also welcomed

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not try: [lastIndexpath release]; lastIndexpath=[indexPath retain];

Comment: Yes Now it is not giving me BAD_ACCESS but what i want is that at a time only one row should be selected

Comment: Can you check following? lastIndexpath=indexPath.row;

Answer (score 3):

You want to mark your selected cell, then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can write code like this:

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
       UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

      cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousSelectedIndexPath];
        [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

     if(previousSelectedIndexPath!=nil)
    {
       [previousSelectedIndexPath release];
       previousSelectedIndexPath = nil;
    }
     previousSelectedIndexPath = [indexPath retain];
}
```

where previousSelectedIndexPath is previously selected index;

Comment: what is previousSelecedIndexPath and how you do i assign the value to it

Comment: It is same as your lastIndexpath ie previously selected indexPath.

Answer (score 2):

Declare **NSIndexPath *lastIndexpath** in .h of your controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
  if( lastIndexpath){
  if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexpath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)

 {

  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexpath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
 }
 else
 {
   [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexpath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

 }}
  lastIndexpath=[indexPath retain]
 if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
 {
   [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
 }
 else
 {
  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Take a variable of type indexpath in .h   

NSIndexPath    *myIndexPath

//Now check it in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: delegate method ..

if(indexPath == myIndexPath)
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else 
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

//and in your didSelect: Delegate method ...

[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
myIndexPath = indexPath;
[tableView reloadData];
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

in delegate method willSelectRowAtIndexPath , get the current selected index path, set accerroryType to none.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *currentSelectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentSelectedIndexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if ([indexPath isEqualTo: currentSelectedIndexPath])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks all,My problem got solved just by Putting retain and using lastIndexpath...